# Is it possible to assign multiple actions to the same controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple MVC Controller that returns a list of files from folders based on View action. `Index()` action contains a list of Collections so then user clicks on `CollectionOne`, the corresponding view is populated. The same behavior is applied to other collections.

The problem is, I have a lot redundant code that I have been able to manage at certain degree by using a private `ActionContent()` method invoked by all actions. So whenever I have a new collection to add to website, I just add a `ActionResult` for this Collection and invoke `ActionContent()` method.

Is there any way to optimize this code to make it more dynamic, without adding a new `ActionResult` every time a need to post a new collection?

My controller looks like this:

```
public class PortfolioController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult CollectionOne()
    {
        return View(ActionContent());
    }

    public ActionResult CollectionTwo()
    {
        return View(ActionContent());
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> ActionContent()
    {
        const string folder = @"~/Content/images/portfolio/";
        var path = folder + ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"];

        var files = Directory
            .EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath(path))
            .Select(Path.GetFileName);

        return files;
    }
}
```

I want to turn it into something like this (to avoid redundancy) using `ActionNames` or maybe proper `route mapping`:

```
public class PortfolioController : Controller
{
    [ActionName("CollectionOne")]
    [ActionName("CollectionTwo")]
    [ActionName("CollectionThree")]
    public ActionResult PortfolioCollection()
    {
        const string folder = @"~/Content/images/portfolio/";
        var path = folder + ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"];

        var files = Directory
            .EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath(path))
            .Select(Path.GetFileName);

        return View(files);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what parameters are for:

```
public ActionResult PortfolioCollection(string id)
{
    const string folder = @"~/Content/images/portfolio/";

    var files = Directory
        .EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath(folder + id))
        .Select(Path.GetFileName);

    return View(files);
}
```

You can make a custom route to assign any URL pattern you want.

Comment: It seems like a good approach but do I need to use one view for all collections?

Comment: Yes if model is same one view can be used

Comment: @Red: You can specify a view name based on the parameter.